# Асинхронное добавление кнопок

Tags: javascript, promise

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы кнопки добавлялись по очереди с задержкой в 1 секунду. Пока получилось так. Кнопки добавляются сразу.

```
function createButtons() {
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    var newButton = document.createElement('button');
                    newButton.innerHTML = 'Кнопка' + i; 
                    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
                }
                resolve('Кнопки созданы'); 
            }, 1000);
        });
        promise.then(function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Отвечая на все ваши комментарии сразу: [стрелочные функции](https://habrahabr.ru/post/268795/)

Comment: Джва года назад это действительно был "Новый синтаксис функций". Зачем использовать VStudio для js, если она их до сих пор не умеет?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
function createButtons() {
  var operations = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    operations.push(
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var iConst = i;
        setTimeout(function() {
          var newButton = document.createElement('button');
          newButton.innerHTML = 'Кнопка' + iConst;
          document.body.appendChild(newButton);
          resolve('Кнопка создана');
        }, 1000 * i);
      })
    );
  }

  Promise.all(operations).then(function(msg) {
    alert("Кнопки созданы");
  });
}
```

`Promise.all` ждёт выполнения всех операций.

P.S. вы можете спросить, зачем мы задаём тут `var iConst = i;`? Если с пониманием этого проблемы, то лучше почитать статьи про замыкание. Если мы не создадим локальную копию переменной `i`, то, когда начнёт выполняться `setTimeout`, то внутри у всех операций значение `i` бы было равно последнему значению по окончанию цикла (то есть, `6`).

Comment: А что это за синтаксис? Просто я компилирую в visual studio и он не понимает ваш синтаксис. Тут он компилируется правильно. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POYBaY

Comment: Все спасибо переделал под студию. Но все равно не ясно, что вы использовали за синтаксис.(Что это за => обозначение.) Так как студия не распознает такой синтаксис и выдает ошибки.

Comment: @Furianec стрелочные функции из es6. Заменил на `function`, теперь должно работать.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
function createButtons() {
  var countBtn = 0;
  var maxCountBtn = 5;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    countBtn++;
    var newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.innerHTML = 'Кнопка' + countBtn; 
    document.body.appendChild(newButton);
    if (countBtn >= maxCountBtn ) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

createButtons();
```

Comment: Что-то ваш код, вообще не компилируется.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить

Comment: Я уже сделал, код ниже. Но спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Собрать обещания в последовательную цепочку можно так:

```js
function addButtonDelay(title, delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var newButton = document.createElement('button');
      newButton.innerHTML = title;
      document.body.appendChild(newButton);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  })
}

var sequence = Promise.resolve();
for (var i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
  sequence = sequence
    .then(addButtonDelay.bind(null, 'Кнопка ' + i, 1000));
}
sequence.then(function() {
  console.log('Все кнопки добавлены');
});
```

---

Для начала мы создаём `Promise.resolve()` - уже "разрешённое"(resolved)обещание.

К нему по очереди цепляем обещания создать кнопку через интервал времени, которое у нас реализовано в виде функции, возвращающий `Promise`.
Цикл выше эквивалентен следующему коду:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => addButtonDelay('Button 1', 1000))
  .then(() => addButtonDelay('Button 2', 1000))
  .then(() => addButtonDelay('Button 3', 1000))
  .then(() => addButtonDelay('Button 4', 1000))
  .then(() => addButtonDelay('Button 5', 1000))
  .then(() => console.log('Все кнопки созданы'));
```

---

Для справки: [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: А что это за синтаксис? Просто я компилирую в visual studio и он не понимает ваш синтаксис. Тут он компилируется правильно. codepen.io/anon/pen/POYBaY

Comment: javascript интерпретируется, а не компилируется. Видимо ваша IDE не поддерживает ES6, а конкретно arrow functions. Убрал их, написал на автомате, не планировал использовать в этом ответе ES6

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код"(в соседних ответах тоже), чтобы убедиться, что в браузере всё работает.

Answer (score -3):

Ответ для студии.

```
function createButtons() {
        var operations = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            operations.push(
                promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var iConst = i;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var newButton = document.createElement('button');
                        newButton.innerHTML = 'Кнопка' + iConst;
                        document.body.appendChild(newButton);
                        resolve('Кнопка создана');
                    }, 1000 * i);
                })
                );
        }
        promise.all(operations).then(function (msg) {
            alert("Кнопки созданы");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, `setTimeout(..., i * 1000)` - не очень хорошая идея. Она не отражает последовательную природу происходящего.

Comment: То есть, вы просто мой ответ скопировали как отдельный ответ? о_О

Comment: Я ничего не копировал. Просто на тот момент у вас был не понятный для меня синтаксис, о котором я вам написал. Я переписал его в код который бы понимала студия и выложил сюда. А потом вы изменили. Спасибо за помощь. Ничего такого не желал, за балами и прочим не гонюсь, мало ли бы вы потом не изменили бы, а кому то пригодилось бы.